# SRAND() is not working in codeblocks?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;


int main ()
{
    srand(5);

    int r = rand() % 100

    cout << r << endl;
}
```

codeblocks throwing this error back saying i didn't declare srand or rand when i need them to just generate random numbers? I know it returns the same nmber everytime as i am learning cpp rn.

Comment: `Code::Blocks` is an IDE. I assume you mean some version of mingw.

Comment: `std::srand` is in  `<cstdlib>`  see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand

Comment: When you've sorted this consider newer things like http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this at the top

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

Comment: saw it from here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/. Let me go and check out your link

Comment: even in my link it uses <cstdlib> but then uses <stdlib.h> in the example. Confusing! thanks Richard for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

"SRAND", which stands for "Seed Rand", is used to obtain seemingly random numbers in the true sense.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<cstdlib>
    #include<cstdio>
    #include<ctime>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
cout<<"The Random Number is "<<endl;
srand(time(0));
cout<<(rand())<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

This can be used to generate OTP's, and other applications in gaming, cryptography, and statistics.